# Why do we use REST to connect to a database on a mobile app?

Tags: database, rest, xamarin.forms, database-connection

I am currently studying how to make cross-platform mobile apps (with xamarin forms), and I have heard that the "correct" way to connect to a database in a non-locale server (in my case located in Azure) is by using Rest Services (or rest APIs, or however is called), instead of connecting directly to the database with the server explorer option of VS like you would do in windows forms for example(using the SQL connection, dataset, etc. Which I think they are not necessary in the first case, I am not sure).

The only answer that I have received about this is that in mobile apps "They are not permanent connections. It connects, gives you data and disconnects. They are Asynchronous connections.", and that this is done "For optimization of connection resources. The mobile is suspended or the user passes the App to the background.".

But I still don't know if this is the actual reason, and if it is I don't understand how it optimizes the connection resources. So if someone has time to explain this I would appreciate it.

Thank you for your time, I hope I have explained myself correctly, and that you all have a great day.

Comment: to connect directly from a mobile app to your DB, your DB **must be exposed directly to the internet** which is a **HORRIBLE** security risk.  It opens your DB to all sorts of attack vectors.  Using web services as an intermediary allows you to add a layer of security between your app, the internet, and your db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason said,the Security issues，with proper authorization having mediator is definitely much more secure than giving a user direct access to the database, because you restrict him to the end points which run only the queries you want to.And from the platform independence and maintenance,if the apps are developed in different languages and on different platforms,it may have benefit to create a common REST interface to allow sharing of data model, caching etc.For performance and scalability，that HTTP layer of your REST API provides another valuable caching mechanism. Your servers for your REST API can put caching headers on their responses, and these responses can be cached at the network layer, which scales exceptionally well.

you could read this link [Why do people do REST API's instead of DBAL's?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277701/why-do-people-do-rest-apis-instead-of-dbals),I think the answers are pretty good